# Would have been ... had been

Tags: tense, subjunctives

I am writing an essay and would appreciate a little help with the language.

> Social science is the knowledge (about the world) that would not have existed **had human not existed**.
>
> Social science is the knowledge (about the world) that would not have existed **if human does not exist**.

Are they both grammatically correct? How to phrase it better?

Comment: As a note, the grammar aside, that's not what the definition of social science actually is; it's about human interactions within society. Your negative version would apply to *any* knowledge that is human-derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...had humans not existed.

Or alternatively -

> ...had humankind not existed.

Comment: Or, as a further options, "had humanity not existed", or any variant with "[...]did not exist".